# Get twitter share response

Tags: twitter, share

I have to make a reward functionality for my customers.In this if any customer share, follow link  of website then I have to store their details.Question Is that how can we get either user shared something or not.Any help would be appreciated.
I am using following code.

```
twitter.com/share?text=Your+Email+Marketing&url=http://blog.abc.com/your-email-marketing.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution using [jquery.twitterbutton.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-twitterbutton-js/downloads/detail?name=jquery.twitterbutton.1.1.js&can=2&q=)

code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.twitterbutton.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#twitterbutton-example').twitterbutton({
   user:'YourUsername',
   title:'jQuery-Twitter-Button Plugin with callback functions',
   onfollow:function(response){
    $('.twitterbutton-uncontent:visible').hide('fade');
    $('.twitterbutton-content').show('fade');
    $.cookie('tw','followed');
   },
   ontweet:function(response){
     alert("hello");
   },
   onretweet:function(response){

   },
   lang:'en'
  });

});
</script>



</head>

<body>
<div id="twitterbutton-example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will alert on click but can't response after tweet success.

Comment: I check your code and ontweet function always return true.

Comment: It won't work, because twitter changed it's behaviour